# WPF Check box command to List or From List

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am new to WPF and not sure whether, whatever i am trying to do is possible or not.

I have checkbox as below :-

```
<CheckBox Name="cbAccess" Checked="cbAccess_CheckedChanged" Unchecked="cbAccess_CheckedChanged">Access To Save</CheckBox>
```

List as below :-

```
List<int> accessList = new List<int>();
```

if checkbox is checked then it should fire command 10 (int) and i will add the 10 in some list. and then unchecked then remove from list.

When first time window get loaded then checkbox will be checked or unchecked on the basis of commnad 10 exist in list or not.

Comment: What exactly is command 10? Are you just asking if you can tie check boxes to commands?

Comment: 10 is integer value which i need to insert in accessList (List<int>)

Comment: Ok... but I don't see a "10" anywhere in your code. Are you also asking how to associate "10" with that check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckBox` derives from `ButtonBase` so you automatically get access to a `Command` and `CommandParameter`. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx)) Using those, you could conceivable do something like:

```
<CheckBox Command="{Binding ToggleItemInListCommand}" CommandParameter="10"/>
```

and have the command function:

```
private void ToggleItemInList(object param)
{
    int item;
    if (int.TryParse(param.ToString(), out item))
    {
       //If its actually an int
       if (myList.Contains(item))
           myList.Remove(item);
       else
           myList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Exposing that method via an `ICommand` is trivial and left to you. While such a solution would work, it doesn't solve the problem of getting the initial state into your `CheckBox`. 
'
Given that you want that behavior as well, I would not use commands at all here, instead using `IsChecked` with a converter. Unfortunately, you'll need to get the collection into the converter on a `DependencyProperty` to make it work. The XAML would look something like:

```
<!-- Resources -->
<local:ListContainsConverter x:Key="ListContainsConverter" Collection="{Binding MyList}"/>
<!-- Main Section -->
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ListContainsConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}"/>
```

Where `ListContainsConverter` is defined:

```
public class ListContainsConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(...)
    {
        //More generic version left as an exercise
        int testValue = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        return collection.Contains(testValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(...)
    {
        bool checked = (bool)value;
        int testValue = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        if (checked)
           Collection.Add(testValue);
        else
           Collection.Remove(testValue)
    }

    public IList<int> Collection
    {
       get { return (IList<int>)GetValue(CollectionProperty); }
       set { SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Collection", typeof(IList<int>), typeof(ListContainsConverter), null);

}
```

This approach is really far better, as it is far easier to keep your state maintained. You are ignoring the `value` piece of the converter, which is a bit odd, but I would take the trade off here.

Comment: I am getting `{"Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."}` error in `<CheckBox...>`  line. Am i missing something?

Comment: @AnchitPancholi You can just use `Path=.` in this case

Comment: look like converter is not working when i click on check uncheck, debug pointer is not hitting to convert and convertback method (I have put debug pointer in starting of both the method).

Comment: @AnchitPancholi I'd check for System.Data exceptions in the output then, you may not have declared the converter correctly or some other issue with the binding.

Comment: converter is :- 
`<local:ListContainsConverter x:Key="ListContainsConverter" Collection="{Binding MyList}"/>` 
and checkbox as :-     
`<CheckBox Content="saveAccess" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ListContainsConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />`
is there anything wrong in above ?

Comment: @AnchitPancholi hmmm... should work. Like I said, with it not even getting *into* the converter, I would look for System.Data exceptions.

Comment: just now i check it goes inside covert method when windows loaded for first time but not when click on checkbox.

Comment: @AnchitPancholi That should trigger `ConvertBack`, not `Convert`

Comment: I got one link which is working the way i am expecting, Not sure if it correct way or not. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56695abf-6720-42e4-b5a7-05e957bf26f7/how-to-obtain-the-dependencyobject-within-ivalueconverterconvertback?forum=wpf

Comment: No its not working as when remove `checkbox` out of `DataTemplate` it dosent work

Comment: its working fine now, i think there was some issue with Binding, we have to set dummy binding to any boolean variable then it worked.